# How To Privately Test A Chrome Extension Disabled Because It Is Not Listed In The Chrome Web Store

Tags: google-chrome, security, testing, google-chrome-extension, permissions

I have written a simple Chrome extension and tested it using developer mode to load the unpacked extension. It works as expected this way.

Because the extension uses `storage.sync` API, I would like to undertake further testing with installations of the extension  as published in the Chrome Web Store.

The Developer Dashboard for Chrome Web Store provides an option to publish to trusted users only:

> Only trusted testers from your developer dashboard can see it.
>   You can also include members of a Google Group that you own or manage.

[image]

When I publish this way the trusted testers listed for my dashboard **can** reach the extension and install it from the Chrome Web Store.  However, the extension is ***always*** disabled upon starting Chrome:

> This extension is not listed in the Chrome Web Store and may have been added without your knowledge. Learn more

We, my testers and I, have not been able to find any way to [enable an extension disabled by Chrome](https://support.google.com/chrome_webstore/answer/2811969?hl=en).  Is there one?  If not, the entire exercise of an "unlisted" publication mode for testing seems pointless.

Comment: Assuming those users are signed-in into Chrome, it sounds like a bug. Check https://crbug.com.

Comment: To confirm, the users are logged in.  They would not reach the extension page if they were not. And they do remain logged in when they encounter the disabled extension.  I'll check there, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The only work around I've found to this situation so far is to set the extension to "unlisted" rather than "published to testers" from the Chrome developer dashboard.

This is not at all satisfying, but did allow some real world testing in an unobtrusive way.

Comment: I'm not sure this is a viable work around either, as I'm seeing some sync behavior in testing that I haven't been able to rule out as being a consequence of being 'unlisted' extension.  Ultimately the may be some bugs we just don't detect without a full publication.